# fetch child's child value from xml using et tree python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

How to fetch all child's child value from xml using et tree python.
Here is the same data

```
 <try>
    <place> 
        <c>place of the city <c>
    </place>
    <details>
        <sex> male or female </sex>
        <phone> phone no </phone>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <code>
                    <areacode> 91 </areacode>
                </code>
                <peraddr> the great city </peraddr>
            </address>
            <address>
                <code>
                    <areacode> 9110 </areacode>
                </code>
                <peraddr> the great wall </peraddr>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </details>
</try>
```

How to fetch the all area code and peraddr value.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please share that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no base code provided to starts with, there are many ways to accomplish this. Below is one possible way, which first find all `address` elements, and then print `areacode` and `peraddr` value from each `address` :

```
>>> raw = '''your xml string here'''
... 
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.fromstring(raw)
>>> for address in root.findall('.//address'):
...     print address.find('.//areacode').text, address.find('./peraddr').text
... 
 91   the great city 
 9110   the great wall
```

Comment: would you mind explaining why single '/' for peraddr?

Comment: @louis It is XPath syntax, btw. To put it simply, `/` is for child element and `//` is for descendants. See the documentation for other [supported XPath syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)

Comment: `address.find('peraddr').text` (without `/` at all) would also work